# While installing this code i am getting an error IP address not found

Tags: apt, ip

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.
While using this code i am getting an error. why so?

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.*/usr/lib
```

Comment: Please [**edit**](https://askubuntu.com/posts/663020/edit) your post and which version of Ubuntu you are running and copy and paste the exact error message. Also indicate if the computer is connected to the internet.

Comment: Besides that: this can NOT be a valid instruction. It is missing  a destination (or at least a space).

Comment: You are probably missing a space between `/usr/local/lib/libgraph.*` and `/usr/lib`.

Comment: It is hard to provide a solution when the original question is replaced with a totally new question. Those who don't know what I am talking about see edit history. This question was about software library installation, now it is about copying files.

Comment: Vishal, please don't change the question completely.

Comment: The new title makes no sense!

Comment: What's the error message you get from this command?

Answer (score 2):

Andrea already answered in the comment.

The proper syntax for `cp` is `cp <origin> <destination>` and you only gave on argument, the origin.
Add a space between `/usr/local/lib/libgraph.*` and `/usr/lib` it'll work

Answer (score -2):

You might be mixing up `cd` and `cp`.  The latter **c**o**p**ies files:

```
$ cp file newfile
```

Now you have a copy of `file` named `newfile` in the same directory.  On the other hand, `cd` **c**hanges into a **d**irectory:

```
~/directory_1 $ cd directory_2/
~/directory_1/directory_2 $
```

which changes you from `directory_1` to it's subdirectory, `directory_2`.

If you try to use `cp` with only one file name after it (like in your original post), you get

```
$ cp file
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘file’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

since `cp` doesn't know what the name of the new file (copy) is.

Comment: @Downvoters... why?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be because the path OP mentions has a wildcard `*` which generally don't work with `cd` unless the only expand to one directory... Or it could be that the question has been dramatically changed from a possible network related issue to a command syntax issue